# how to avoid Linebreak in _webout?

Tags: sas

I build dynamically a very long String with variables encapsulated in HTML.
Then i use ods HTML _webout to create a HTML-Page with the information.
My Problem is, when the String gets longer than 4096 characters, it does a linebreak. If this linebreak is somewhere in an HTML-Command, this breaks my page. When i use LRECL it limits the value to 4096, no matter which value i use there.
Sascode:

```
/*Some data generating and other stuff first which is not important here*/
...
/*then the output*/
data _null_;
set myData;
file _webout LRECL=32767;
put somedata;
/* somedata is like '<table><tr><td>someinformation</td> <td>moreinformation</td>...<td>lastinformation</td></tr></table>*/
run;
```

If i look at sourcecode of page it can happen something like:

```
<tr><td>Info1</td><td>1</td><td>C</td><td>$1.</td></tr>...   ...<t
r><td>info80</td><td>10</td><td>C</td><td> </td></tr>
```

so it breaks after the 4096th character and does not write the tr correctly (or other html-code, depending on the Resultstring), which leads to some wrong displayed output.

I build a workaround to split the output string in several strings with maximum 4000 length and put them all out, but that is not a nice Solution, can somebody give me a tip how to solve this more elegant?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i found a solution for my Problem, but i dont understand it ;(

It depends on a given encoding value for a webout, so my testing with Sas 9.3 and IE8 gave following results:

```
   file _webout LRECL=32767;
limited result to 1024 characters per line
   file _webout encoding=utf-8 LRECL=32767;
limited result to 4096 characters per line
   file _webout encoding=ANY LRECL=32767;
no visible limitation in my test cases
```

So, if somebody got the same Problem, mayb he can use the workaround by giving the correct encoding value.

But maybe somebody can explain why the output linelength seems to be influenced only by encoding value, but not by the lrecl statement.

Answer by techsupport was like:

LRECL works as documented, the Problem is browserspecifc, search browser options, maybe there is something you can activate or deactivate for a solution of your Problem.

I did not invested time in searching for browseroptions wich fix the problem, because we have many different customers (most of them use IE8) which call the processes, and i can not contact all and tell them how to change their browser

my Workaround:
Split strings in smaller parts or use encoding values.

Comment: This may be a good candidate for a SAS help ticket.  If you do submit one, you should paste in their response here.

Comment: I submitted a ticket, lets see how long answer takes

Comment: Ok, tech support answer was: LRECL works as documented, the Problem is browserspecifc, search browser options, maybe there is something you can activate or deactivate for a solution of your Problem. A disapointing answer, made a workaround anyway, a combination of i split my strings in strings of a smaller size and use encoding.

Answer (score 1):

4096 sounds like limitation of editor used for viewing . Since you've coded lrecl=32767, i do not think you should have issue with the HTML breaking at any point. Check out below example and you can view the source in IE/Chrome/Firefox, the line is continuous and does not break. I'm guessing you are hardcoding values and that's when editor used to create the html table get the line limit view to 4096 w/o wordwrap and you get a feeling that line is continuous and when you copy paste that in SAS Stored Process, you see the break while displaying in Browser

```
data _null_;
file _webout LRECL=32767;
put '<table><tr>';
do i =1 to 4000;
put '<td>' i 8. '</td>' @;
end;
put '</tr></table>';
run;
```

Comment: When i use your example, it stops the output after 3915. Sourcecode shows ... 
3913</td><td> 3914</td><td> 3915</td
and then ends... Could this be a browserspecific problem? (i have to use IE8 and SAS 9.3 because of Customer).
I dynamically build the String, i read some Metadata-information in a datastep and want to put them out as webpage, because of the structure of the data i have to put it in one string.
I

Comment: that's weird, i'm using SAS 9.3 Stored Process with the latest version of chrome and i'm getting till 4000. What browser are you using. Is your browser restricting view til 3915? does the view source shows 4000?

Comment: yeah, i think IE 8 has 4096 limitation...i think i have seen this before..try single <td> </td> tag per line. that should help you overcome your problem

Comment: Ok, i builded a new process with nothing but your code and tested it in IE8 and Firefox, in both it stops after 3915</td
Could this be a Server-Specific Problem?